# Cloud Server SMTP forwarding to wrong server before sending email and JS .POST() takes 2 minutes

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter, post, apache2, sendmail

I've created an issue a bit out of my league and require some expertise advice!

I have a cloud server on `Rackspace` that hosts my sandbox `CodeIgniter` app that works perfectly. I created a new cloud server and copied the image over from the sandbox server to the production server. Everything is EXACTLY THE SAME.

I added a `virtualhost` and got the production app up and running.

Here's the issue: The sandbox app sends email through `jQuery UI` and the `CI email class` and on success shows the dialog, "complete!" almost immediately.

On the production app, you click the send button, and it takes exactly TWO MINUTES for the `.POST()` to return successful - which means, the dialog doesn't change for two minutes...

Here's a link to what chrome inspector found: http://persogenics.com/post.jpg

Just to check, I sent emails to myself from both systems to see what the `SMTP Headers` looked like.

```
THE SANDBOX SERVER 'RECEIVED' SECTION:
-------------------------------------------
Received: from test.persogenics.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by test.persogenics.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id r24G1I8O020018
    for <tonylefler@gmail.com>; Mon, 4 Mar 2013 16:01:18 GMT
-------------------------------------------

THE PRODUCTION SERVER 'RECEIVED' SECTION:
-------------------------------------------
Received: from prod-server (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by test.persogenics.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id r24FqNkY031102
    for <tonylefler@gmail.com>; Mon, 4 Mar 2013 15:52:23 GMT
-------------------------------------------
```

Would anyone know why the production server has the words `by test.persogenics.com` in it? I can't find any code in the production app that has those words in it! In fact I've used `site_url()` and such so it shouldn't make a difference what domain name it is...

My only conclusion is that it's forwarding the email to the sandbox server, then it's sending it off... But again I'm a noob and I really have no idea...

I'm using `UBUNTU 10.4`, `CodeIgniter 2.1`, and `Apache2` if that helps...

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How long does it take on prod-server to get SMTP server greeting?

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
```

2) What is reported on prod-server by the two test comands below (execute second one as root):

```
hostname --fqdn
 echo '$j' | sendmail -Am -bt
```

*P.S. You may ask sendail related question at news:comp.mail.sendmail*

Comment: I'm marking this right first off because your the only one who answered, and also you were right on the money with the FQDN.

Comment: I met up with a IT guy and he showed me the hostname commands on `putty`. Evidently there's hostname settings only accessible through the command line that `sendmail` uses to verify that the server is legit - which I guess slows down the whole mail process.

Thanks again!

Comment: Next time I would recommend posting EXACT delay in seconds. It may give valuable clues what should be checked first.